# Topbar disappeared in elementary os 5.1.7

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel

Topbar disappeared in elementary os 5.1.7.
When I type "wingpanel" in terminal, it gives me the following error:

**(wingpanel:4691): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 22:15:40.645: Settings schema 'io.elementary.wingpanel.keyboard' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap**

Please help me out.

Comment: I've never seen this error, so I'm not sure if this will work. I'd personally start by reinstalling it. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install wingpanel`. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what else to try, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: The issue was solved. I don't know how but the last command I tried was `sudo apt install --reinstall slingshot-launcher`. But still thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Hi I'm having this issue and none of the previous solutions worked for me